# What is the role of embeddings in a deep recurrent Q network?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, dqn, deep-rl, embeddings

When describing the model architecture for a deep recurrent q network, the authors of the paper [Learning to Communicate with Deep Multi-Agent Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06676.pdf)

> each agent consists of a recurrent neural network (RNN), unrolled for $T$ time-steps, that maintains an internal state $h$, an input network for producing a task embedding $z$, and an output network for the Q-values and the messages $m$. The input for agent $a$ is defined as a tuple of $\left(o_{t}^{a}, m_{t-1}^{a^{\prime}}, u_{t-1}^{a}, a\right)$.

Can someone explain what the purpose of the embedding layer is in this specific context?

Implementation can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/MJ10/2c0d1972f3dd1edcc3cd17c636aac8d2/dial.ipynb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the input network is to embed the input tuple into a state/task representation, that can then be fed into the RNN hidden state at each time step.

$(o^a_t,m^a′_{t−1},u^a_{t−1},a)$ (input) $\rightarrow$ input network (embedding) $\rightarrow$ $z_t$ (task representation)

---

According to to section 6.1 of the paper, the input is a tuple represented as $(o^a_t,m^a′_{t−1},u^a_{t−1},a)$. Each of these  terms is described in sec 3 as:

- $o_t$ - The observation. The authors assume a [POMDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_observable_Markov_decision_process)
- Two types of actions:

  - $u_t$ - An environment action selects by all the agents at each time step in exchange for a team reward
  - $m_t$ - A communication action, observed by other agent but has no direct impact on the reward or env
- $a$ - The agent (This being a multi-agent DQN algorithm)

They form the input to the Deep Recurrent Q-Network architecture.

The purpose of the embedding network is to receive a tuple of these inputs and produce a state
embedding $z$. This state embedding is then fed  into a hidden state $h^a_{t-1}$ of the RNN.

Though the authors refer to it as an input network that produces embedding, in practice, they use different embedding functions for each of these inputs. The final task/state embedding $z_t^a$ is expressed as a sum:

$$
z_t^a = \text{MLP}(o_t^a) + \text{MLP}(m_{t-1}) + \text{LookupTable}(u_{t-1}) + \text{LookupTable}(a)
$$

The summed embeddings are all of the same size.

This answer makes an assumption that by "embedding layer" you meant the input embedding network. *Since the paper makes no reference to a single embedding layer in the model architecture.*